# How can I evaluate $\int \frac {x^2 + 1}{x^4 + x^2 +1} dx$ by partial fraction method?

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I evaluate $\int \frac {x^2 + 1}{x^4 + x^2 +1} dx$ by partial fraction method?

Could anyone tell me please?

Comment: What do you know about partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition provides an algorithm to rewrite your integrand. Have you tried to apply it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Notice that $1+x^2+x^4 = (1+x^2)^2-x^2=(1+x^2+x)(1+x^2-x)$, so your function can be rewritten as
\begin{align}\frac{A}{1+x+x^2}+\frac{B}{1-x+x^2} & = \frac{A-Ax+Ax^2+B+Bx+Bx^2}{1+x^2+x^4} \\
& = \frac{(A+B)+(B-A)x+(A+B)x^2}{1+x^2+x^4}
\end{align}
and your conditions are $A+B=1$, $A-B = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Not what you're asking, but here's a different method

$$ \int \frac{x^2+1}{x^4+x^2+1}dx = \int \frac{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + 1}dx = \int \frac{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}}{\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 + 3}dx $$

Let $u = x-\frac{1}{x}$, then the integral becomes

$$ \int \frac{1}{u^2+3}du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\frac{u}{\sqrt{3}} + C $$